# Bind a model object with dynamically created 10 labels in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios-binding

I am working on Xamarin forms and faced an issue where I need to bind Model object to dynamically created 10 labels using for loop. I'm able to bind a single label using setBinding like

```
 var label = new Label
    {
        Text = "",
    };

    label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "Name");
    label.BindingContext = myModelObj;
```

but how to bind for dynamically created labels. I am creating labels using for loop like

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ 

var label = new Label
{
    Text = "",
};

label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "Name");
label.BindingContext = myModelObj;
 }
```

how to assign different values for different label which are inside **myModelObj**

Comment: Did it helped you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but unluckly it doesnt because I want to make a grid type layout which should have dynamically generated labels align horizontally. So I cant use List in this case.

Comment: Is there any way to bind a list of integers to a stacklayout. ?

Comment: Why wont you use List instead of stack?

Comment: How to align labels Horizontally in listView ? So that it looks like a grid ?

Comment: VerticalOptions="Center"? Please be concise and specific with your question. If you have another question open a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your binding values in an array and using i to access them?

```
var labelBindings = new string[10] { "Name", "Next", "Another",...};

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ 

  var label = new Label
  {
      Text = "",
  };

  label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, labelBindings[i]);
  label.BindingContext = myModelObj;
 }
```